# Command line arguments parsing in ballerina similar to argparse in python

Tags: parsing, command-line-arguments, ballerina

Is there any way to parse the command line arguments in ballerina? From what I have seen you can use only positional arguments. What I would like to do is something like this:

```
//main.bal
public function main(string? name, int? age) returns error? {
    if (name is string && age is int) {
        io:println("Hello " + name);
        io:println("Age " + age.toString());
    }
}
```

And then run the programm as follows:

```
bal run main.bal -- --name John --age=18
```

But this does not work, because it takes "--name" as the first positional argument and "John" as the second positional argument. So it throws an error:

```
error: invalid argument 'John' for parameter 'age', expected integer value
```

And if I run it as follows then it runs:

```
bal run main.bal -- John 18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `configurable` support for this.
Check this example:

```
import ballerina/io;

configurable string name = ?;
configurable int age = ?;

public function main() returns error? {
    io:println("Hello " + name);
    io:println("Age " + age.toString());
}
```

Then while running you can provide values as following:

```
bal run main.bal -- -Cname="Ballerina" -Cage=5
```

The result is

```
Hello Ballerina
Age 5
```

[Check this guide](https://ballerina.io/learn/making-ballerina-programs-configurable/defining-configurable-variables/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you.

I already had tried it with configurable after reading the docs, but did not think that the capital letter "C" was neccessary before the arguments name. I thought that it was just an example -Ckey.

Comment: Yes, the `C` is for `Configurable` (I guess). You can skip that using @MaryamZi's answer

Answer (score 2):

The arguments can be passed by name if they are specified for options.

If the arguments are part of a record like

```
public type Details record {|
    string name?;
    int age?;
|};
```

and the `main` function has an included record parameter of this type to specify options

```
public function main(*Details f) {
    string? name = f?.name;
    int? age = f?.age;

    if name is string && age is int {
        io:println("Hello ", name);
        io:println("Age ", age);
    }
}
```

it can be run as follows

```
$ bal run main.bal -- --name=Jo --age=25
```

This was introduced in Swan Lake Alpha5 and the release note provides more information - https://ballerina.io/downloads/swan-lake-release-notes/swan-lake-alpha5/#improved-command-line-argument-parsing.